# It is advisable to keep a zTable always open?

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe3

I'm developing a system of registration of products and cashiers.

My main Form is to screen requests and from it open the other registration screens (Unit of Measure, Products, Payment, Customer, etc.)

For each of these screens I have a zTable in a Data Module. And OnShow / OnClose of each form, open / close the zTables.

As the main screen I need these open zTables, my question is: It is advisable I open them in the main form and keep them open during the entire time that my application be running?

Comment: I wouldn't advise it. But someone else might. Which makes me wonder if this is really opinion based.

Comment: Is the back-end database you're using client-server based (like MS SQL Server) or file-system-based like Sqlite?

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: I was wondering that (about opinions), but then there are objective differences depending on how the db back-end works.

Answer (score 3):

There's basically two types of database system which Delphi apps can access, client-server (C/S) ones and file-system-based ones.  The reason I mention that is that there are different technical considerations involved in deciding whether it's ok leaving tables open for the duration of an app.  So it's important to know which type a given app is accessing.

The key difference between the two types is which process is responsible for file i/o and maintaining the integrity of the db, your app or a separate server process like Sql Server/Interbase/Firebird/MySql.

With a file-system based db, where your app is responsible for doing the file i/o (even if it is via a Dll as with Sqlite), if the db-access involves writing to the db, there is the risk that if your app crashes, or the user kills it via TaskMan or Ctl-Alt-Del, say, the db's files will be damaged or left in an inconsistent state, rendering the db potentially unusable.  File i/o requires in-memory structures which are at risk from being corrupted by things such as wild pointers, etc, and if this is going on in your app, there is greater risk to the data than if it were being handled by an industrial-strength server, and the longer you leave them open, the greater the risk.

So, as with file access generally, it's really not very good practice to leave files open any longer than you really need them to be.  Just leaving them open to close later when your app closes is asking for trouble really.

You can take a more relaxed view if your db is server-based, because it's the server's responsibility to make sure that file updates are handled as they should be, and servers tend to be coded on the assumption that the client is quite likely to just "go away" without tidying up after itself, and to operate in a safer environment than the typical client-side Delphi app.

That's not an excuse, though, for a Delphi app not doing its housekeeping promptly by doing things like calling ApplyUpdates (if your dataset type supports it), or the equivalent for your dataset type as soon as practicable after the client-side data is changed, or not tidying up after itself when it closes (e.g. by closing the connection with the server, because open connections tend to consume server resources even when the connection isn't being actively used).

Apart from the possibility of your app crashing, the longer you leave sending the server changes the user thinks (s)he has made not relayed back to the server, the greater the risk of another user changing the data in a way which is inconsistent with what this one has done.

Anyway, although there's a lot more to it than just leaving tables open, regardless of whether your db is server-based or file-based, an answer to your "is it advisable" is no it is not, there's very little to be said for it and serious technical/practical factors against it, especially with file-based dbs.  But, leaving tables open when working with a server-based db is a lot less hazard-prone than with a file-based one as long as you don't do things like waiting until just before your app closes to write any changed data back to the server.

Even with file-based dbs (actually I would say "especially with") there is a lot to be said for using in-memory datasets like Delphi's native TClientDataSet as the db objects the user interacts with via the GUI and leaving it to other dataset components, working in short bursts, to interact with the db itself.

Btw, not that it makes any difference but I'm assuming that when you say "zTables", you mean datasets which are components of the Zeos library).